# Help with Particular Solution of DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am assigned the task of finding the particular solution for the given problem:
$$
y' = 1/t \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & t\\
  -t & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix} + t \begin{bmatrix}
  cost\\
  sint\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

You are told that a fundamental matrix for the complementary system is:
$$
Y = t\begin{bmatrix}
  cost & sint\\
  -sint & cost\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that I can arrive at my particular solution given this and the f(t) provided in the problem statement through the following process:
$$
u' = Y^{-1}f
$$

The particular solution is then given by:
$$
X_p = Yu
$$

I have arrived at a particular solution of:
$$
X_p = \begin{bmatrix}
  tsint\\
  -tcost\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, the book states that the particular solution should be:
$$
X_p = \begin{bmatrix}
  tsint\\
  0\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Could someone verify that this is the correct particular solution?  I have gone through my process twice and arrived at the same answer.  Perhaps someone could shed some light on where I may be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Amzoti - It is really t.

Comment: @Amzoti - Thank you.  I look forward to hearing back from you!